# JavaScript instanceof and moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm attempting to understand types in the JavaScript world. My page is using [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). I have a function that sometimes returns a `moment()` and other times, returns a `string` (it's legacy code gone wild).

My code kind of looks like this:

```
var now = getDate();
if (now instanceof moment) {
  console.log('we have a moment.');
} else {
  console.log('we have a string.');
}


function getDate() {
  var result = null;
  // Sometimes result will be a moment(), other times, result will be a string.
  result = moment();
  return result;
}
```

When I execute the code above, I never get `we have a moment.`. Even if I manually make set `result = moment();`. Why is that? Am I misunderstanding `instanceof` or `moment`?

Comment: Try printing "type of moment()" to make sure you are expecting the right value.

Comment: try using typeof, and debug:
console.log(typeof now);

Comment: should use `typeof now === "string"`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

First of all, `instanceof` isn't perfectly reliable.

Second of all, `moment()` returns instance of `Moment` class that isn't exposed to user. Following code prove this:

```
moment().__proto__.constructor // function Moment()
moment().constructor === moment; // false
```

Third of all, `moment` provide function `moment.isMoment` that will solve your problem.

And last, but not least - your code should use consistent return types - always return `moment` instances or always return strings. It will reduce your pain in future.

You can ensure that you always have `moment` instance by calling `moment` function - `moment(string)` equals in value `moment(moment(string))`, so you can just always convert your argument to `moment` instance.

Comment: shouldn't you be checking `moment().constructor === moment`?

Comment: I think this is out of date. `isMoment` is undefined. Also, the difference between `isMoment()` (or `isValid()`, which I think is the current equivalent) and typeof/instanceof can be fairly significant in the right circumstances.

Comment: You should call moment.isMoment(moment()) and not moment().isMoment().

Comment: [The docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/) says: "From version 2.11.0, you can also test for a moment object by instanceof operator: moment() instanceof moment // true"

Comment: I was attesting to my friend that js would be capable of giving erroneous values for `instanceof` and there it is. I code in JS but sometimes those little things make it feel a little less reliable.

Answer (score 56):

*Moment version 2.13.0*

There is a static method `.isMoment`:

[image]