# Momentjs, Property 'toISOString' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: angular, typescript, momentjs

I have the following code which worked until now but now `value.toISOString()` throws a compiler error. I have upgraded from Angular 7 -> 8 which brought with itself an upgrade to Typescript 3.4.5.
Any idea what is causing this?

```
    import * as moment from 'moment';    
    ...

    private getQueryStringParameters(parameters: any) {
        if (!parameters) {
            return '';
        }

        let queryString = '?';

        // tslint:disable-next-line:forin
        for (const key in parameters) {
            const value = parameters[key];

            if (value !== undefined) {
                if (value instanceof Array) {
                    value.forEach(
                        item =>
                            (queryString +=
                                key + '=' + encodeURIComponent('' + item) + '&')
                    );
                } else if (value instanceof moment) {
                    queryString +=
                        key +
                        '=' +
                        encodeURIComponent('' + value.toISOString()) +
                        '&';
                } else {
                    queryString +=
                        key + '=' + encodeURIComponent('' + value) + '&';
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance for any input!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you write a `getQueryStringParameters` function in the first place, instead of relying on Angular's own methods of forming the query params string out of an object (both for Angular Router and HttpClient)?

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38330983/2050306

Comment: what does this output `typeof value`

Comment: @robert Thanks, changing it to that fixed the compile problem. If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: @mbojko I'm not sure, I didn't write this code. But I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
value instanceof moment
```

Try using **isMoment** method:

```
moment.isMoment(value)
```

See the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-a-moment/) and [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xxhtzh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) demo.